# webpack-require-http webpack encore symfony - require external js

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I tried to add this extension:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-require-http

to webpack encore:

```
.addExternals({
          'webpack-require-http'  :require('webpack-require-http')
    })
```

but I got:

```
encore dev --watch
Running webpack ...

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.externals should be one of these:
   string | object { <key>: string | object | boolean } | function | RegExp | [string | object { <key>: string | object | boolean } | function | RegExp | [(recursive)]]
   -> Specify dependencies that shouldn't be resolved by webpack, but should become dependencies of the resulting bundle. The kind of the dependency depends on `output.libraryTarget`.
   Details:
    * configuration.externals should be a string.
      -> An exact matched dependency becomes external. The same string is used as external dependency.
    * configuration.externals['webpack-require-http'] should be a string.
    * configuration.externals['webpack-require-http'] should be an object.
    * configuration.externals['webpack-require-http'] should be a boolean.
    * configuration.externals should be an instance of function
      -> `function(context, request, callback(err, result))` The function is called on each dependency.
    * configuration.externals should be an instance of RegExp
      -> Every matched dependency becomes external.
    * configuration.externals should be an array:
      [string | object { <key>: string | object | boolean } | function | RegExp | [(recursive)]]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I want to load the php-generated js to webpack.

In vendor.js add:

```
require('http://10.2.0.2/vars.js');
```

This url file is php generated js.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this one, Greg?